# What DLC includes the online pass in Saints Row The Third

Tags: saints-row-the-third

I have a used copy of Saints Row The Third and I have all of the cooperative story packs.  Do any of these packs come with the Saints Row The Third online pass for xbox 360?

Answer (score 1):

Sadly, no.  The only way to get the online pass is [to buy it directly](http://marketplace.xbox.com/en-US/Product/Online-Pass/2b0352ad-2b09-4324-b4ff-440de5cb5ade) or get one free in a new copy of the game.  It is not included with any of the other DLC.